# Range of function $ f(x) = x\sqrt{x}+\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x}}-4\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right),$ Where $x>0$

Tags: calculus, inequality, optimization

> Find the  range of the function $\displaystyle f(x) = x\sqrt{x}+\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x}}-4\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right),$ where $x>0$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Let $\sqrt{x}=t\;,$ Then $\displaystyle f(t) = t^3+\frac{1}{t^3}-4\left(t^2+\frac{1}{t^2}\right)\;,$

Now After Simplification, We get $\displaystyle f(t) = \left(t+\frac{1}{t}\right)^3-3\left(t+\frac{1}{t}\right)-4\left[\left(t+\frac{1}{t}\right)^2-2\right]$

Now Put $\displaystyle t+\frac{1}{t} = u\;,$ Then $\displaystyle \sqrt{x}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} = u\;,$ So we get $u\geq 2$ (Using $\bf{A.M\geq G.M}$)

And our function convert into $\displaystyle f(u) = u^3-4u^2-3u+8\;,$ Where $u\geq 2$

Now Using Second Derivative Test, $f'(u) = 3u^2-8u-3$ and $f''(u) = 6u-8$

So for Max. and Min., We put $\displaystyle f'(u)=0\Rightarrow u=3$ and $f''(3)=10>0$

So $u=3$ is a point of Minimum.

So $f(2)=8-4(4)-3(2)+8 = -6$ and $f(3) = -10$

and Graph is Like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+of+f%28u%29%3Du%5E3-4u%5E2-3u%2B8+from+u+belong+to+%282%2Cinfty%29)

So Range is $$\displaystyle \left[-10,\infty \right)$$

My question is can we solve it any other way,  Like using Inequality

If yes, Then plz explain here

Thanks

Comment: If $x:=t^2$, shouldn't $4(x+1/x)$ become $4(t^2+1/t^2)$?

Comment: Thanks Trold I have edited it.

Comment: You should add that $t>0$, or define $\sqrt{x}=t$. Because if $x=t^2$, then $\sqrt{x}$ can be either $t$ or $-t$, depending on the sign of $t$.

Comment: I've edited it to make it $\sqrt{x}=t$.

Comment: your approach looks promising

Comment: i have the same result as you

Comment: Note $f(u)=(u-3)^2(u+2)-10\ge-10$.

Comment: Thanks  user236182, Thanks Macavity , But How can we adjust in that manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$\color{blue}{x\sqrt{x} + \dfrac1{x\sqrt{x}}-4\left(x+\dfrac1x\right) = \underbrace{\dfrac{\left(1+\sqrt{x}\right)^2\left(x-3\sqrt{x}+1\right)^2}{x^{3/2}}}_{\text{Is non-negative}}-10}$$
Hence, the minimum is $-10$

Comment: Thanks Leg, Would you like to explain me How can we adjust it in that maner.

Comment: @juantheron Expand the right hand side and you will obtain the left hand side. Of course, there was a bit of reverse engineering involved in the fact that we need that the minimum was $-10$, occurring at $\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{3\pm\sqrt5}2}\right)^2$

Comment: @Leg then this is what they call an ad-hoc solution isnt it?

Comment: @G-man In that sense, any solution procedure is ad-hoc. Integrals are ad-hoc, trigonometric formulas are ad-hoc, summation formulas are ad-hoc, and so on...

Answer (score 0):

HINT: $$f'(x)=3/2\,\sqrt {x}-3/2\,{x}^{-5/2}-4+4\,{x}^{-2}$$
solving for $x$ we obtain
$$1,1/4\, \left( \sqrt {5}-3 \right) ^{2},1/4\, \left( \sqrt {5}+3 \right) ^{2}$$
plugging $1$ in $f(x)$ we obtain $-6$ plugging the other two terms in $f$ we get $$-10$$